# What to do if I accidentally delete the branches dir that's parallel to trunk and tags dirs

Tags: svn

I know the revision number that this mistake happened, then how can I roll back?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the [svn manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html) section *Undoing Changes* the following procedure is applied to *undo* changes:

```
svn merge -r 303:302 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
svn commit -m "Undoing change committed in r303."
```

Comment: the idea is correct, but the URI is not - it should be without `/trunk` since the deleted directory is `branches`

Comment: @Dmitry Yudakov: The commands are plain copies from documentation. You're right, that I did not refer to your post. Nevertheless one should be able to adapt the url as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You copy the branches directory from the last not deleted revision back into the current directory structure.

```
svn cp /path/to/repo/branches@Just-before-delete-revision /path/to/repo/
```